# Android: Load JSON-File from "raw" directory

Tags: android, json

I have jet another problem with my project. To display some Panoramas in my application I'm using `PanoramaGL` lib. For the library I use a `JSON-File`, which provides some settings, how it will be displayed. I want to let the user change some of those settings, like accelerometer rotation and so on. So I need to access these values in my `JSON-File`. And this is the part, where I'm really struggling.

The File is in raw folder and for `PanoramaGL` I'm passing a value like: "res://raw/json_k55".

```
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
pano = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pano");
panorama = new PLJSONLoader(pano);

if(panorama!=null)
    this.load(panorama, true, new PLTransitionBlend(2.0f));
}
```

Since I'm not using actual `HTTP-Request` or `getRessource()`, I really don't know, how to get some objects of this file changed, for example on button click. The JSON-File is here: [json_k55](https://github.com/Artishock88/Hobby360/blob/master/app/src/main/res/raw/json_k55.data)

Comment: You can save file from assets to application folder and after you can modify it as you want

Comment: PanoramaGL is accessing it in raw-folder and loads pictures for a cubic-panorama, which are also in the same folder. So I cant move it somewhere else (tried it, could not open the pics).

Comment: It is probably your url base in json looks like `res://raw`. So if you try change it to `file://<folder name>` and also put images there

Comment: And if my JSON is in the assets folder, do I load it with a inputstream or what is the cleanest way?

Comment: I never worked with this library. If this is the right class https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/source/browse/trunk/+panoramagl-android/PanoramaGL/src/com/panoramagl/PLJSONLoader.java?r=17 then it should handle file opening itself

Comment: panorama is working without problems and loading json and pictures.

What I want is to change the json on the fly, to give user a choise, if he wants some of the feauters (like sensorial rotation //virtual reality - like).